# MySql XOR Update - comparing rows and updating values

Tags: mysql, sqlite, sql-update

```
SELECT * FROM products where [...]
```

Will return 2+ entries:

```
+------------+-------------+
| product_id | provider_id |
+------------+-------------+
| 0000001    |      NULL   |
+------------+-------------+
| 0000004    |      0032   |
+------------+-------------+
| 0000009    |      NULL   |
+------------+-------------+
```

I'm looking for (if it exists) a MySQL command to populate the **provider_id** from **the row where it is not null** to the others **NULL**:

```
+------------+-------------+
| product_id | provider_id |
+------------+-------------+
| 0000001    |      0032   |
+------------+-------------+
| 0000004    |      0032   |
+------------+-------------+
| 0000009    |      0032   |
+------------+-------------+
```

It sure can be done in PHP by issuing a couple of query executions. But I'm willing to make it neat with the least of processing in php code and most in MySQL/SQLite.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straightfoward method:

```
UPDATE products SET provider_id = (SELECT provider_id FROM products WHERE [...])
WHERE [...] -- same condition here
AND provider_id IS NULL -- this is probably useless
```

This assumes that only one row has (`provider_id IS NOT NULL`) in your original query. It will fail with an error message (and do nothing) otherwise.

Comment: Wow... I missed that! So simple and yet I missed! Thanks!